# Cordova пуш уведомления OneSignal

Tags: android, cordova, уведомления

Настроил пуш уведомления на Android от onesignal. На андроид 4.2 все нормально приходит. Но на андроид 5.0 уведомления не показываются. Хотя девайс корректор регистрируется в системе, только не получает уведомления.
Написано на cordova. Скажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать?